# Authorization token in php

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

When a user login to a system web service will send an authorization token as follows, I need to add these tokens as a header for all the get request that user will make after login I have written following code using curl through a not found exception can anyone help me to find a solution

```
token:{"user" :"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ2NjIzNTc1OSwiZXhwIjoxNDY2MjM5MzU5LCJuYmYiOjE0NjYyMzU3NTksImp0aSI6ImJjZmExYjc5OGYyYTY2MTAyMWY2OTM3NTc3MTkyZTNhIn0.ai91pavOiqs_41bFD5A9X2IsoniP1FHvRswR6coTwXc"}


$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ2NjIzNTc1OSwiZXhwIjoxNDY2MjM5MzU5LCJuYmYiOjE0NjYyMzU3NTksImp0aSI6ImJjZmExYjc5OGYyYTY2MTAyMWY2OTM3NTc3MTkyZTNhIn0.ai91pavOiqs_41bFD5A9X2IsoniP1FHvRswR6coTwXc";                  
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/logout');                                                                       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//return json_decode($result);
return view('checking', ['title' => $result]);
```

Comment: Should it be a `GET` or a `POST` request? You have mentioned that the user will make `GET` requests, but you are actually sending `POST` request via `curl`.

Comment: Seems your sending tokens for ```logout``` shouldn't be ```login```?